# Table extending out of a card

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I created a card using the bootstrap. Within that card, I intend to insert a table with data.

My problem is that when reducing the screen (check responsiveness), the data in the table comes out of the card.

How can I make this so that the table doesn't extend out and instead it has a horizontal scroll to it, can someone help me?

Thanks

[image: table pic]

DEMO

```css
.card {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ECF2F9 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}

.header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #4D4F5C;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:40%">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header header">
            <h1>My Table</h1>
        </div>
        <table class="card-table table-borderless myTable" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">Title</th>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">Street</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let pr of Data; let  a = index;" class="tableColor">

                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.title}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.street}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you going to add scroll or break the content into multiline?

Comment: I want to add a scroll bar within the card

Comment: wrap table in `table-responsive` div to get scroll content, like this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Comment: @MinalChauhan already tried that it isn't working in my case

Comment: @LakshyyaKothari it's working properly in my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jegqdxk8/

Comment: @MinalChauhan maybe some other library is interfering or something with this solution in my case but thank you.

Comment: @MinalChauhan adding a max width in the card table did it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow-x: scroll;` and move the card header to outside of the card.

```css
.card {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 2px solid red;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ECF2F9 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}

.header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    color: #4D4F5C;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:40%">
        <div class="card-header header">
            <h1>My Table</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="card">
        <table class="card-table table-borderless myTable" style="overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">Title</th>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col tableTitles">Street</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let pr of Data; let  a = index;" class="tableColor">

                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.title}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.id}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableTitles">
                        {{pr.street}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```